# How to determine in apex if user is connected via salesforce for outlook or on the web?

Tags: apex, api, user

I have a problem where if i am connected via salesforce for outlook and that i create a task or event, i should be able to detect that the task or event is been created via the connector and not salesforce. Because in my trigger i have different operation to be done in the different cases.

We are investigating the solution to map a field in outlook to a dummy field in salesforce, but we are investigating this solution also. Has anyone been able to do this ?

I checked the documentation for a field on the user that could tell me if the user is currently doing the operation via web or any other device, but failed to do so.

Answer (score 3):

You can Query the LoginHistory Object to get all the details of the User's login history. There is a field available called `Application` which gives you the application used to access the organization. Filter the result based on the latest login time. Hope this helps.

```
SELECT Application FROM LoginHistory WHERE UserId =<UserId>
```

Apex Example: (replace 005i0000002pcDw with user's UserId )

```
LoginHistory lh = [select Application from LoginHistory where UserId ='005i0000002pcDw' order by LoginTime desc limit 1];
System.debug(lh.Application);
```

Comment: Since it was a request for `Apex`, maybe you could write a complete method that returns a `Boolean` result? Should only be a couple lines.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thanks for your suggestion. I have added the required code snippet.

Comment: But what happen if the user is connected on the web and in his salesforce for outlook, even if he creates the event from salesforce for outlook, he will still have active session on both side isn't it?